# Puppeteer - Running a function inside a frame

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, puppeteer

I'm trying to execute a function inside a Frame but without success.

```
await page.evaluateHandle(()=>{
  console.log(window.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[3].contentWindow)
  console.log(window.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[3].contentWindow.fiAbrePagina)
});
```

See that in the console log, the function exists in the object, but when I try to access the function, it does not exist.

[image: Chrominium console output]

Looking at the console and inspecting the window object the function exists:

[image]

I need help, how to execute a function inside a frame?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`page.frames()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageframes) to obtain an array of all frames attached to the page. Then you can use [`frame.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameevaluatepagefunction-args) to execute a function within the browser context inside a certain frame.

Also, make sure you use [`page.on('console')`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-console) to handle [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) from within the page DOM environment:

```
page.on('console', msg => {
  for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; ++i) {
    console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
  }
});

const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'example');

await frame.evaluate(() => {
  console.log(window.fiAbrePagina);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the [contentFrame](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.9.0&show=api-elementhandlecontentframe) from the frame element, something like this:

```
let frameElement = await page.evaluateHandle(() => window.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[3]);

frameElement = await frameElement.asElement();

const frameContentFrame = await frameElement.contentFrame();

await frameContentFrame.evaluate(() => console.log(fiAbrePagina.toString()));
```